# TFS API get TestResults in a specific date range

Tags: api, tfs, tfs-2015

How can I get test results completed in a specific date range using the TFS API?
I used queries like

```
SELECT * FROM TestResult WHERE completedDate BETWEEN '2016-09-03' AND '2017-05-19'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TestResult WHERE completedDate > '1.5.2017'
```

But both resulted in a "Bad request" response of the TFS API.

Is there something wrong in the syntax querying a date field?

Querys for other fields work well, e.g.

```
Select * From TestResult Where TestCaseId = 25406
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is:

```
var testresults = teamProject.TestResults.Query("SELECT * FROM TestResult WHERE DateCompleted < '2017-05-24 07:41:44.137'");
```

The Field is **DateCompleted** and the time format is `2017-05-24 00:00:00.000`.

**Note:**

The DateCompleted stored in database is using UTC time, so when you run the query you should convert your local time to UTC time to get more accurate results

Comment: Thanks. No idea, why the field in the json response is namde completedDate and in the SQL statement itself "DateCompleted".